# Create Generic method for mapping of entity to dto in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

I have written a method which map the entity to dto using modelMapper, now I want to reuse it for other entities, so I want to transform the below method into generic type.

```
private VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO mapToDto(MsilVehicleLayout msilVehicleLayout) {
        log.info("MsilVehicleLayoutServiceImpl::mapToDto::START");
        this.modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        TypeMap<MsilVehicleLayout, VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO> propertyMapper = this.modelMapper
                .createTypeMap(MsilVehicleLayout.class, VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO.class);
//      propertyMapper.addMappings(skipFieldsMap);
        propertyMapper.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(v -> Boolean.TRUE).map(MsilVehicleLayout::getId,
                VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO::setMsil));
        VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO imageAndLayoutDto = this.modelMapper.map(msilVehicleLayout,
                VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO.class);
        return imageAndLayoutDto;
    }
```

Now the problem is that, it is tightly coupled because of below line,

```
propertyMapper.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(v -> Boolean.TRUE).map(MsilVehicleLayout::getId,
                    VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO::setMsil));
```

because i am using model mapper, but few properties I want to set with static values, so the above code is nothing, but setting the `setMsil` method of `VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO` with `Boolean.TRUE`.

Now the first argument `MsilVehicleLayout::getId` is just like a mock argument because `mapper.map()` expecting two argument, so first argument is just mock one and has nothing to do with `VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO::setMsil`

Now, I want to figured out a way to either isolate these dependency out of this snippet or is there a way to leverage the Reflection API in order to set the custom values ??
this is the problem statement which I am expecting the answer for, please help

Comment: How do you want to make your function generic, when you have specific commands inside? (e.g. `.map(MsilVehicleLayout::getId, VehicleImageAndLayoutDTO::setMsil)`)

Comment: I will plan to isolate that addMapping part, or I'll think some of the way where we leverage the reflection API's invoke method in such case, if you have some suggestion, please let me know, most welcome

Comment: Then ask your question with more details. Throwing some code and expecting us to understand what's on your mind is too optimistic :)

Comment: Please see my edits, you will get more clarity this time